# Is it common and does it make sense to travel to the Maldives as a single person?

Tags: solo-travel, maldives

Since many years ago I have wanted to visit the Maldives. I was amazed by the nice beaches, clear waters, and nice resorts with a hut over the sea. However I am afraid after one or two nights I will feel a bit lonely as I travel alone. In addition I am afraid I will feel a bit socially displaced as I understand it is mostly couples in a romantic mood over there.

I know I could spend the time there doing some diving and kind of sports or so but it is not my point.

The question is, is it so uncommon to travel alone to the Maldives? If so, would that be a weird experience?

Comment: Plenty of relationships started when two single people meet each other while traveling :)

Comment: Yes but if not many singles there... then it's difficult. Right? hahah

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common? Probably not as much as couples going.  But it's a common enough query that even CNN has an article on it:

[Solo travelers to Maldives have plenty to see and do](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/maldives-solo-travelers/index.html)

Activities even for singles include the local food, swimming, diving, yoga, day trips and more.